# 1998 Dodge Ram 1500 V8 magnum wont turn over

Tags: starting, dodge, ram

can anyone help me i woke up this morning to go to work crunk the truck up it cranked and drove fine well at 10 went back out to the truck and it wouldnt turn over at all i got it towed to a shop where they replaced the starter they finished replacing it and i crunk it up and it ran and drove fine until i got home i was at the house maybe 30 min when i forgot i needed to go to the store so i go out to the truck and same problem again will not turn over at all only other thing done was a oil change about 4 days ago any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do you have power to the dash and stuff when you go to start it? You turn the key to "On" and what does the truck do? Then you turn it to start and nothing? Give us a little more information on how the truck is behaving. It sounds like there could either be a power connection issue or your there's an issue with the ignition switch. I don't believe your truck should have come with a smart key, so don't think that'd be the issue.

Comment: the inside lights come on as well as radio and outlets but the motor when going to crank it will not turn over all you hear when trying to crank it is nothing just silence

Comment: Do the lights/radio stay on when you turn the key over to start?